# Line breaks using FMDB and Obj-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, fmdb

I'm relatively new to iOS programming, so please bear with me.

I'm creating an app that calls recipes from a table view, then listing the measurements and ingredients as labels in the detail view. I catalogued my recipes in Google Sheets, downloaded it as a .csv file and populated a table using SQLiteStudio. I then exported the database, and using FMDB, plopped it in my app. Everything works fine there and I'm able to retrieve various fields.

What I'm trying to do is list out the measurements and ingredients so that it displays with line breaks:

`0.5 oz.
1.0 oz.
1 jigger`

And not as: `0.5 oz., 1.0 oz., 1 jigger` which is how I wrote it into the Google doc.

I've tried using `\n` in the SQLite viewer but it outputs it as a String rather than encoding it as a new line. However, when I view the accompanying .sql file, TextMate2 reads it as new lines.  I'm not sure if I have to apply some code within my tableviewcontroller implementation file where I call the FMDB or elsewhere.

I have been looking for a solution for awhile now but no luck. Any help in steering me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**CocktailListTableViewController.m**

```
- (NSMutableArray *)recipeCocktails {
recipeCocktails = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSString *databasePath = [(AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] databasePath];

FMDatabase *fmDB = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:databasePath];

if(![fmDB open])
{
    NSLog(@"Could not open DB, try again");
    return nil;
}

FMResultSet *results = nil;
results = [fmDB executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM recipesCocktails"];
NSLog(@"result %@ ",results);
if ([fmDB hadError]) {
    NSLog(@"DB Error %d: %@", [fmDB lastErrorCode], [fmDB lastErrorMessage]);
}
while ([results next]) {
    Cocktails *cocktails = [[Cocktails alloc] init];
    cocktails.recipeName = [results stringForColumn:@"recipeName"];
    cocktails.recipeMeasure = [results stringForColumn:@"recipeMeasure"];
    cocktails.recipeIngred = [results stringForColumn:@"recipeIngred"];
    cocktails.recipeGlass = [results stringForColumn:@"recipeGlass"];
    cocktails.recipeShaker = [results stringForColumn:@"recipeShaker"];
    cocktails.recipeDirections = [results stringForColumn:@"recipeDirections"];

    [recipeCocktails addObject:cocktails];
}

[fmDB close];

return recipeCocktails;
```

**CocktailsDetailTableViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
self.title = cocktails.recipeName;
self.recipeIngred.text = cocktails.recipeIngred;
self.recipeMeasure.text = cocktails.recipeMeasure;
```

Comment: How are you showing your list? UILabels? In a UITextView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see you're trying to store all the ingredients as one long, pre-built string, and I think that approach is not the best.

It's gonna work, but it's not future-friendly or simply... usual.

I strongly suggest having a new table that knows all the possible ingredients, with ID's and other informations of your will (color, average weight, picture* and whatnot)

*(* please note that it's not advised to store images in a SQL database and you'd rather store references to where you saved them as files or URL's)*

Once you have that table, you're golden. You simply reference an array of ingredients in your recipe table. For example `[1,27,133]`, and with that you can do what you want. You have an array of ingredient objects, which you can treat how you see fit.

I would, for example, loop over it and create labels under each other and you'd have your lines.
I could also simply use an NSMutableString and fill it with the ingredients.name (again, using examples)
You could fill a UITextView with newlines between each ingredient (by using the NSMutableString and adding newlines between each object name).

And more importantly, you can modify everything without having to re-work your layouts or labels or re-write your whole database because you have static newlines ingredients for each recipe.

That is the most important point I wanted to make. With that approach you can remove any ingredient from any recipe without having to think really far or risk forgetting something. You could also permanently destroy any ingredient to every recipe by removing it from the ingredient table. Same for adding new ones. Or saying you want to change the name of ingredient X, you dont' have to do it in every recipe, and so on.

EDIT: Answering your question in comment

To load the recipes in the tableview and the ingredients on the detail page, you can do it like so :

- You load all your recipes in an array and display that (I think you're successful already on that part).
  Note that all the recipes have a property called "Ingredients" which is an array of ingredient keys/ids/something
- On cell tap, you want to load the ingredients that you only know the ID of, you simply get them from the array of Id's that you stored in your recipe, and SELECT them from your db.

Globally, you have no idea what the ingredients are until the user taps : if you don't need to display them in the table view, then you don't need to laod them yet. But you already know their id (otherwise you wouldn't be able to find them!).

Comment: I ended up creating a new table with a row of ingredients as well as a recipeID that I had in my first table. I'm using the recipeID as the primary key for both tables (is this the correct way to link the information in the tables together? They're in the same db). 

I then created a new NSMutableArray to hold the ingredients. I'm having trouble displaying the ingredients though b/c I don't think the tables are connected via the recipeID without calling it. Do you know how I would call the recipeID so that the recipe name shows up in the table view and the ingredients would load in the detail?

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches to this problem.

1. One approach is to store the list of ingredients in as a single text field, with new line characters inside the string. SQLite (and FMDB) handle this fine.

   From the UI perspective, you would then show this text field in a multiline `UITextField` or a `UILabel`. If you use `UILabel`, make sure the number of lines is set to something other than 1 (i.e. either zero or the actual number of lines).

   The trick here is now to get this newline string into the database. And it depends upon how you're doing this. But if you're using some SQLite tool, you cannot use `\n` sequence, as that's not acceptable SQL syntax. You can use `x'0a'` or `char(10)`:

   ```
   insert into foo (bar) values ('baz' || x'0a' || 'qux');
   ```

   or:

   ```
   insert into foo (bar) values ('baz' || char(10) || 'qux');
   ```

   or, if using SQLite command line tool, you can just insert newline:

   ```
   insert into foo (bar) values ('baz
   qux');
   ```

   But you cannot use `\n` sequence. You can do this from your Objective-C code, but not from within a third party SQLite tool.
2. The other approach is to store the list of recipes and the list of ingredients for each recipe in two different tables (e.g. `recipes` and `ingredients`). Then you could store each of the ingredients in a separate row in the `ingredients` table.

   This strikes me as a more logical implementation. If you did this, you would then have the choice as to how you wanted to show the list of ingredients (separate `UILabel` controls, a `UITableView`, or, if you really wanted to, concatenate them together, separated with newline characters and show them in a single multiline control.